# Missing notification hub device registrations

Tags: azure-notificationhub

There were recently some issues with the availability of Azure Notification Hubs. While the service is back online now, multiple users have registered with our app in the meantime. These users have tags registered in our db, but it seems those tags are not registered with the actual Notification Hub.

How do I handle device registrations that came in to my service during Azure Notification Hub outage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Notification Hubs server side SDK. [Registering for Notifications using the WebAPI Backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#registering-for-notifications-using-the-webapi-backend) is an example of how to do that.

Comment: After testing through the Notification Hubs REST API, we have confirmed that all devices registered in our service are in fact also registered with the Notification Hub. However, for both Android and iOS devices, push notifications are not delivered to the end user until the user has opened the app at least once (re-registered with the notification hub).

The results are the same whether sending from our service or sending in Test Sending in the Azure portal using a tag.

Any input? Do the users have to be re-registered with APNS or GCM in addition to Azure?

Thanks :)

Comment: No need to re-register directly with APNS or FCM because that's what NH is for. From the information you have provided it's hard to tell exactly why the original registrations do not result in pushes (maybe sandbox vs production certificate in iOS?), but since you're seeing that re-registered devices do get notifications, that's good to know.

Comment: Further testing shows no devices registered before yesterday's issue are receiving push notifications until opening the app once. We also see this in a dramatic drop in msg open rates today. These devices have valid registrations in NH. Also tested on a device with the app installed, app not opened after the issue. No notifications. I then used the NH rest api to 1) get the current registration values, 2) delete the registration, 3) recreating the registration with the exact same values from step 1. Now (without opening the app first), the device receives notifications. Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, it's difficult for me to keep track of what's going on. Please update the original question with detailed information about any code or configuration changes on your end, timelines and code snippets. Otherwise, it's impossible to help.